# getting transaction id from org.neo4j.driver.v1.Transaction api (bolt api)

Tags: neo4j

How to get transaction id from org.neo4j.driver.v1.Transaction api.

I did not see any method to get that.

Can anybody help

Comment: Why do you need it?

Answer (score 0):

Currently, the 2 implementations of the `org.neo4j.driver.v1.Transaction` interface do not store anything like a "transaction id".